# How to compile and execute code dynamically?

Tags: php, .net, python, c

There are some websites (like this [one](http://www.codility.com)) that allows users to submit code in different languages and the system compiles and executes test cases on them. As a developer, I am curious to know how they do this and how are they supporting multiple languages (PHP, Python, C, .NET, javascript)?

Isn't it possible that the code submitted can be malicious thereby jeopardizing the environment that they execute the code on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> am curious to know how they do this and how are they supporting multiple languages (PHP, Python, C, .NET, javascript)?

Simple: Have multiple language installations installed and invoke the correct one for the given input (which is of course given by the user).

> Isn't it possible that the code submitted can be malicious thereby jeopardizing the environment that they execute the code on?

Yes, of course. However, there are countless potential countermeasures. Sandboxing the process in some of the various forms developed over the years, killing off the process after a given time, preventing access to potentially dangerous functionality, etc. See [Codepad's about page](http://codepad.org/about) for what a real site doing this has to say about it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for that particular site, but usually they create a restricted environment, called a [sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29). Within this environment they can further restrict the availability of functions to programs run there. This could also be done by blocking certain API calls within the language.

[Chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) on *nix is one way of creating a sandbox.

Comment: Is there a way to create a sandbox in a windows environment?

Comment: Off the top of my head I can think of a Virtual Machine solution like VirtualBox or VM Ware, and Google found this as first link for sandboxing+windows - http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2009/03/11/five-sandboxing-apps-to-protect-your-windows-computer/